# iOS. Method adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, text, fonts, size, uilabel

I need to fill in a rect with some text. The size of rect is fixed.

I use the following function:

```
- (void)drawText:(NSString *)text onView:(UIView *)view inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    lbl.minimumFontSize = 1;
    lbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
    [lbl setText:text];
    lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [view addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl release];
}
```

Then I write something similar to this:

```
[self drawText:@"Asdfghjkl;" onView:view inRect:CGRectMake(45, 40, 85, 13)];
[self drawText:@"qwertyui" onView:view inRect:CGRectMake(173, 31, 126, 22)];
```

And I get the cutted text. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main trouble is that some text fits width only but it must fit both width and height.
So the fastest solution for me is to make a bigger transparent UILabel and put a text inside it using alignment

Answer (score 2):

As Gargolev said, it will adjust to fit width *only*.

You should hence choose the right fontSize to fit the height you're provided with.

To do that at runtime without prior knowledge of the font you're going to use, a simplistic solution would be:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myView.bounds];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:1.f];
float fontAspectFactor = 1.f/label.font.lineHeight;
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:myView.height*fontAspectFactor];
[myView addSubview:label];
```